# Jquery Toggle Select All

Tags: jquery, select, html-select

I'm using this to Select All entries in a drop down list with the id 'test'

```
$("#All").click(function () { $('#test option').attr('selected', 'selected'); });
```

I'd like to change it to Select/Deselect All. Any idea how I get it to do that ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need toggle for select values,

http://jsfiddle.net/TTpRU/1/

```
 <a href="javascript:;" id="All" rel="0">Select All</a>
<select name="test" id="test" multiple>
    <option>One</option>
    <option>Two</option>
    <option>Three</option>
    <option>Four</option>
    <option>Five</option>
</select>

$("#All").click(function () { 

    if( $(this).attr('rel') == 0)
    {
        $('#test option').prop('selected', true); 
        $(this).attr('rel' ,1).text('Deselect All');
    }
    else
    {
        $('#test option').attr('selected', false);
        $(this).attr('rel',0).text('Select All');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's

```
.prop('selected', true)
```

OR

```
.attr('selected', true)
```

You would be setting selected to selected otherwise.

Comment: Use `.prop()` instead of `.attr()`

Comment: The [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#entry-longdesc) has a section regarding `.prop()` & `.attr()` that is very helpful.